# Is an Android EVENT_ID Unique Across Calendars?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am trying to manage calendar events in my app using Android's calendar provider. On the [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) the following methods to **delete** an event and to **open** an event in the calendar are shown:

To **delete** an event:

```
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MyActivity";
...
long eventID = 201;
...
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
Uri deleteUri = null;
deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
int rows = getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);
Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Rows deleted: " + rows);
```

To **open** a specific event in the calendar using calendar intent:

```
long eventID = 208;
...
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
   .setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

That works pretty well but I noticed that, different than in other transaction such as creating and retrieving events, the calendar id does not seem to be of significance. Why is that so? **Can I safely assume that the system guarantees all event IDs to be unique across all calendars?** Or could there be multiple events with the same ID, and what happens then?

Comment: The fact that the events table includes a column for the calendar id suggests that all calendars share the same events table. That in turn would mean that the event IDs (= row IDs?) are unique within that table and therefore across all calendars. I'm not certain enough to trust on my conclusions and would be grateful for an expert to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that assumption is correct. The event ID you pass with the Uri maps directly to the row `_id` field, which is the primary key of the events table. 
So each event has a (system wide) unique id.

If you follow the calls of `deleteEventsInternal` in [CalendarProvider2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java#3115) you can see that the ID you passed is compared to the `_id` field of the events table.

The selection in [line 3222](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java#3222) eventually evaluates to `_id = <the ID you passed>`

Regarding your question "Why is that so?":

The relationship between calendars and events is a one-to-many relationship, which means one calendar may contain multiple events, but one event belongs to exactly one calendar.

The way this is represented in the calendar database is the standard way of modeling this in relational databases, see http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/

In database design this is also called the [Second normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).

Comment: This is Calender_id  means The _ID of the calendar the event belongs to. it means multiple events can belong to a calendar which has a unique id, Actually, i'm retrieving all events which are created by me but I get all events list including default holiday, I saw in the log the calendar contains holiday which has a unique calendar id that is 3 and where I have added events which has a calendar id is 4, I want to know that how do I get events list which is created by me, how can i recognize calendar id of my event list.

Comment: @farhana from your description its hard to tell what the problem is. You should post this in a new question, providing code snippets which show what your problem is.